# Function of two integers that has not repeated values

Tags: natural-numbers

In order to implement a software I need a function $f:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that:
$$(x' \neq x \lor y' \neq y) \Rightarrow f(x,y) \neq f(x',y')  $$

It's very easy to implement an algorithm that implements such a function, but I was not able to find an analytical representation of it.

coult you help me?

Comment: What's wrong with having an algorithm?

Comment: Just a performance issue. An equation would be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual "Cantor zig-zag" mapping can be defined as

$$ (x,y) \mapsto \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} + x $$

It has the (sometimes) nice property that it is surjective, that is, every natural number is the image of *some* pair, so nothing goes to waste.

Comment: $(a, 0)$ and $(0, 1 + a)$ are both sent to the same value. I think you need $(x + y + 1)$ in the numerator instead of $(x + y - 1)$ to make it work.

Comment: @Arthur: Hm, yes, fixed. I forgot there are $N+1$ combinations with $x+y=N$, not just $N$.

Comment: The inverse function would be $x+y=floor(sqrt(2n+2)-0.5)$

Answer (score 3):

If you are not afraid of being wasteful, try $f(x,y)=2^x3^y$. This is however hardly suitable for limited software.

Comment: Along similar lines: $3^x+2^y$, although proving the required condition may be a challenge (if it actually holds)...

Comment: @abiessu: It doesn't: $3^1+2^1 = 5 = 3^0+2^2$. And if you don't like zeroes, $3^1+2^3 = 11 = 3^2+2^1$.